# Button click triggers onclick for itself and another button

Tags: android

I have 2 `Button`'s in a layout (belongs to a fragment). Let's call them button1 and button2. When I click button2, it triggers onclick for button2. When I click button1, it triggers onclick for button1 (itself), and then for button2. I can't seem to figure out why this is happening.

```
public class StartFragment implements View.OnClickListener {

    @BindView(R.id.button1)
    Button button1;
    @BindView(R.id.button2)
    Button button2;



    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_start, container, false);
        ButterKnife.bind(this, view);
        button1.setOnClickListener(this);
        button2.setOnClickListener(this);
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()){
            case R.id.button1:
                Log.d("LOG","button1 click");
            case R.id.button_by_country:
                Log.d("LOG","button2 click");
        }    
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have missed `break` statement in the `switch`:

```
 @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()){
            case R.id.button1:
                Log.d("LOG","button1 click");
                break;  // <!---  ADD HERE

            case R.id.button_by_country:
                Log.d("LOG","button2 click");
                break;  // <!---  ADD HERE
        }    
    }
```